# Python, ¿Como salir de bucle while si dura más de 5 minutos?

Tags: python, while, time, redes-neuronales

Tengo un proceso, una función; que unas veces dura menos de 5 minutos y otras veces demasiado tiempo. La cuestión es que no puedo controlar ni saber cuanto tiempo durará ese proceso con antelación por que es un entrenamiento de un modelo (random forest) y depende de muchos factores. Lo que sí sé, es que si dura más de 5 minutos no lo necesito.

Por tanto quería montar algo así...

```
while (segundos<300):
    procesa()
```

Lo he intentado con time con tictoc, etc. pero no hay manera.

Ahora tengo esto:

```
    # Entrenar
    t = TicToc()
    t.tic()
    while t.toc() < 300:
        self.model.fit(self.X,self.Y)
```

Pero me da el siguiente error:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Alguien me puede indicar como podría hacerlo?

Comment: Saludos, probaste este [metodo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13293360/11209718)?

Comment: Voy a ver y te digo.

Comment: Hmm me dice eso: AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGALRM' This won't work on Windows because Windows doesn't implement SIGALRM. stackoverflow.com/a/52779986/1768141 – Vinayak Nov 5 '19 at 19:53

Comment: Lo estas haciendo en windows no? No hay posibilidad de que utilices linux para desarrollar esto?

Answer (score 2):

Deberias probar con la funcion `Time`. Mira el siguiente ejemplo de la siguiente [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293269/how-would-i-stop-a-while-loop-after-n-amount-of-time):

```
import time
timeout = time.time() + 60*5   # 5 minutes from now
while True:
    test = 0
    if test == 5 or time.time() > timeout:
        break
    test = test - 1
```

Obviamente adaptandolo a lo que necesites, en este caso llamar a `fit`

Comment: Desconozco la eficacia, pero yo lo haría asi: `timeout= datetime.datetime.today() + timedelta(minutes=foo)`. y los minutos los declararía en `foo`

Answer (score 1):

Si prefieres usar TicToc lo tenias casi bien, el problema es que el comando `t.toc()` solo hace el dispay en pantalla pero te devuelve un `None`, por eso se queja de que en tu condicion del while estas comparando un `None` del toc con un `int`.

Simplemente cambia el metodo `.toc()` por `.tocvalue()` que te devuelve el tiempo transcurrido en segundos:

```
from pytictoc import TicToc
# Entrenar
t = TicToc()
t.tic()
while t.tocvalue() < 300:
    self.model.fit(self.X,self.Y)
```